# Cipher with a hidden key

Tags: cipher

The challenge is to decode this cipher:

```
TJ KS JX AP GN DT DG FE ER EU UA HJ
```

The key is attached to this question. Try to find it!

Comment: What kind of encryption have you used?

Comment: could be hex numbers with a direct mapping... 15 different symbols

Comment: Have a feeling that `The key is attached to this question` has a lot to do with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message, decoded using Vigenere, is:

> thisisanencodededmessage

and the key is

> accabf

Key and text were decoded using a program I have written. The code cannot be made available. But there are probably similar ones online that aren't as accurate. If the message had no English words in it would have not been found without his key that is hidden in the question.

I actually do not see the key anywhere in here but I didn't look for it to hard either. Based on the length of 6 it's probably the hex color coding to one of the elements on this site.

Comment: I encoded the message using a completely different method but you got it right. Very impressive.

Comment: "encodeded"...?

Comment: @Len I updated answer but it isn't going to help anyone learn. Plus the op said it wasn't the right method unless he did individual Caesar shifts.

Answer (score 4):

I assume the OP is still waiting for the key to be identified.  The correct key is:

> **022015** which is the month and year that are "attached to this question".
>
> Using numbers as the key makes this a Gronsfeld cipher instead of a Vigenère cipher.
>
> The result is the same (with a double "ed"): thisisanencod**eded**message